# Search in lists of lists by given index

Tags: python, list

I have a list of two-item lists and need to search for things in it.

If the list is:

```
list = [['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['b','d']]
```

I can search for a pair easily by doing

```
['a','b'] in list
```

Now, is there a way to see if I have a pair in which a string is present in just the second position? I can do this:

```
for i in range (0, len(list)):
    if list[i][1]==search:
       found=1
```

But is there a (better) way without the `for` loop? I don't need to know `i` or keep the loop going after it's found.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You're always going to have a loop - someone might come along with a clever one-liner that hides the loop within a call to `map()` or similar, but it's always going to be there.

My preference would always be to have clean and simple code, unless performance is a major factor.

Here's perhaps a more Pythonic version of your code:

```
data = [['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['b','d']]
search = 'c'
for sublist in data:
    if sublist[1] == search:
        print "Found it!", sublist
        break
# Prints: Found it! ['a', 'c']
```

It breaks out of the loop as soon as it finds a match.

(You have a typo, by the way, in `['b''d']`.)

Comment: At this point in my python "career" I favor this approach since it is very easy to read. I might come back to try the other ones for performance, though. My list gets quite big at one point. Is there any place where I can compare performance of the different approaches?

Comment: Use the `timeit` module for performance testing of this kind of thing: http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html

Comment: What if we don't know whether the character which we're searching for is in the [0]th,[1]st,[2]nd etc. position within the nested list? e.g. we're searching for 'b', using this method it would only return ['a','b'] rather than ['b','d'].

Comment: @Chris-Jr: Replace `if sublist[1] == search` with `if search in sublist`.

Answer (score 85):

Here's the Pythonic way to do it:

```
data = [['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['b','d']]
search = 'c'
any(e[1] == search for e in data)
```

Or... well, I'm not going to claim this is the "one true Pythonic way" to do it because at some point it becomes a little subjective what is Pythonic and what isn't, or which method is more Pythonic than another. But using `any()` is definitely more typical Python style than a `for` loop as in e.g. [RichieHindle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1156114/56541),

Of course there is a hidden loop in the implementation of `any`, although it breaks out of the loop as soon as it finds a match.

---

Since I was bored I made a timing script to compare performance of the different suggestions, modifying some of them as necessary to make the API the same. Now, we should bear in mind that fastest is not always best, and being fast is definitely not the same thing as being Pythonic. That being said, the results are... strange. Apparently `for` loops are very fast, which is not what I expected, so I'd take these with a grain of salt without understanding why they've come out the way they do.

Anyway, when I used the list defined in the question with three sublists of two elements each, from fastest to slowest I get these results:

1. [RichieHindle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1156114/56541) with the `for` loop, clocking in at 0.22 μs
2. [Terence Honles' first suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158136/56541) which creates a list, at 0.36 μs
3. [Pierre-Luc Bedard's answer (last code block)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18412156/56541), at 0.43 μs
4. Essentially tied between [Markus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1156582/56541) and the `for` loop from [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1156087/56541), at 0.48 μs
5. [Coady's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1157153/56541) using `operator.itemgetter()`, at 0.53 μs
6. Close enough to count as a tie between [Alex Martelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1156628/56541) with `ifilter()` and [Anon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1156128/56541), at 0.67 μs (Alex's is consistently about half a microsecond faster)
7. Another close-enough tie between [jojo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13588121/56541), mine, [Brandon E Taylor's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1156145/56541) (which is identical to mine), and [Terence Honles' second suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158136/56541) using `any()`, all coming in at 0.81-0.82 μs
8. And then [user27221's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30449870/56541) using nested list comprehensions, at 0.95 μs

Obviously the actual timings are not meaningful on anyone else's hardware, but the differences between them should give some idea of how close the different methods are.

When I use a longer list, things change a bit. I started with the list in the question, with three sublists, and appended another 197 sublists, for a total of 200 sublists each of length two. Using this longer list, here are the results:

1. [RichieHindle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1156114/56541), at the same 0.22 μs as with the shorter list
2. [Coady's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1157153/56541) using `operator.itemgetter()`, again at 0.53 μs
3. [Terence Honles' first suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158136/56541) which creates a list, at 0.36 μs
4. Another virtual tie between [Alex Martelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1156628/56541) with `ifilter()` and [Anon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1156128/56541), at 0.67 μs
5. Again a close-enough tie between my answer, [Brandon E Taylor's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1156145/56541) identical method, and [Terence Honles' second suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158136/56541) using `any()`, all coming in at 0.81-0.82 μs

Those are the ones that keep their original timing when the list is extended. The rest, which don't, are

6. The `for` loop from [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1156087/56541), at 1.24 μs
7. [Terence Honles' first suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158136/56541) which creates a list, at 7.49 μs
8. [Pierre-Luc Bedard's answer (last code block)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18412156/56541), at 8.12 μs
9. [Markus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1156582/56541), at 10.27 μs
10. [jojo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13588121/56541), at 19.87 μs
11. And finally [user27221's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30449870/56541) using nested list comprehensions, at 60.59 μs

Comment: That's a great answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

```
>>> the_list =[ ['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['b''d'] ]
>>> any('c' == x[1] for x in the_list)
True
```

Answer (score 15):

the above all look good

but do you want to keep the result?

if so...

you can use the following

```
result = [element for element in data if element[1] == search]
```

then a simple

```
len(result)
```

lets you know if anything was found (and now you can do stuff with the results)

**of course** this does not handle elements which are length less than one
(which you should be checking unless you know they always are greater than
length 1, and in that case should you be using a tuple? (tuples are immutable))

if you know all items are a set length you can also do:

```
any(second == search for _, second in data)
```

or for len(data[0]) == 4:

```
any(second == search for _, second, _, _ in data)
```

...and I would recommend using

```
for element in data:
   ...
```

instead of

```
for i in range(len(data)):
   ...
```

(for future uses, *unless you want to save or use 'i'*, and just so you know
the '0' is not required, you only need use the full syntax if you are starting
at a non zero value)

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> my_list =[ ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd'] ]
>>> 'd' in (x[1] for x in my_list)
True
```

Editing to add:

Both David's answer using **any** and mine using **in** will end when they find a match since we're using generator expressions.  Here is a test using an infinite generator to show that:

```
def mygen():
    ''' Infinite generator '''
    while True:
        yield 'xxx'  # Just to include a non-match in the generator
        yield 'd'

print 'd' in (x for x in mygen())     # True
print any('d' == x for x in mygen())  # True
# print 'q' in (x for x in mygen())     # Never ends if uncommented
# print any('q' == x for x in mygen())  # Never ends if uncommented
```

I just like simply using **in** instead of both **==** and **any**.

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 7):

What about:

```
list =[ ['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['b','d'] ]
search = 'b'

filter(lambda x:x[1]==search,list)
```

This will return each list in the list of lists with the second element being equal to search.

Answer (score 5):

Markus has one way to avoid using the word `for` -- here's another, which should have much better performance for long `the_list`s...:

```
import itertools
found = any(itertools.ifilter(lambda x:x[1]=='b', the_list)
```

Comment: Ah, good, Alex is here. ;-)  Obviously, the gen exp's use the word 'for' - but if we allow that, interpreting the goal as avoiding the standard for loop structure instead of the word 'for' itself, how do all the answers given compare in terms of performance?

Comment: @Anon, I have no time right now to run the usual -mtimeit thingies (OSCON is on, & I'm pretty busy with it;-), but from previous experience I know that itertools tend to perform like greased lightning. All answers save Markus's stop at the first match so they're all equally fast in this sense.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing wrong with using a gen exp, but if the goal is to inline the loop...

```
>>> import itertools, operator
>>> 'b' in itertools.imap(operator.itemgetter(1), the_list)
True
```

Should be the fastest as well.

Answer (score 2):

k old post but no one use list expression to answer :P

```
list =[ ['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['b','d'] ]
Search = 'c'

# return if it find in either item 0 or item 1
print [x for x,y in list if x == Search or y == Search]

# return if it find in item 1
print [x for x,y in list if y == Search]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> the_list =[ ['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['b','d'] ]
>>> "b" in zip(*the_list)[1]
True
```

`zip()` takes a bunch of lists and groups elements together by index, effectively transposing the list-of-lists matrix. The asterisk takes the contents of `the_list` and sends it to `zip` as arguments, so you're effectively passing the three lists separately, which is what `zip` wants. All that remains is to check if `"b"` (or whatever) is in the list made up of elements with the index you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a deep find for dictionaries and didn't find one.  Based on this article I was able to create the following.  Thanks and Enjoy!!

```
def deapFind( theList, key, value ):
    result = False
    for x in theList:
        if( value == x[key] ):
            return True
    return result

theList = [{ "n": "aaa", "d": "bbb" }, { "n": "ccc", "d": "ddd" }]
print 'Result: ' + str (deapFind( theList, 'n', 'aaa'))
```

I'm using == instead of the in operator since in returns true for partial matches.  IOW:  searching aa on the n key returns true.  I don't think that would be desired.

HTH

Comment: for what it's worth, I don't think you need the result  variable at all. just return false and the end

Answer (score 0):

I think using nested list comprehensions is the most elegant way to solve this, because the intermediate result is the position where the element is. An implementation would be:

```
list =[ ['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['b','d'] ]
search = 'c'
any([ (list.index(x),x.index(y)) for x in list for y in x if y == search ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

A list of list of strings: `list_to_search`

The string that we look for: `"item_to_find"`

```
    list_to_search: List[list[str]] = ...
result = [sublist for sublist in list_to_search for item in sublist if item == "item_to_find"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Given below is a simple way to find exactly where in the list the item is.

```
for i in range (0,len(a)):
sublist=a[i]
for i in range(0,len(sublist)):
    if search==sublist[i]:
        print "found in sublist "+ "a"+str(i)
```