# python: for loop compact representation

Tags: python, numpy

Python, Numpy

Is there a more compact way to operate on array elements, without having to use the standard for loop.?

For example, consider the function below:

```
filterData(A):
    B = numpy.zeros(len(A));
    B[0] = (A[0] + A[1])/2.0;
    for i in range(1, len(A)): 
        B[i] = (A[i]-A[i-1])/2.0;
    return B;
```

Comment: check out [np.diff](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), which works on both numpy arrays and python native arrays

Comment: I think you should look at this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156087/python-search-in-lists-of-lists

Comment: `B[1:]=(A[1:]-A[:-1])/2.0` can replace your whole loop.

Answer (score 5):

Numpy has a [diff operator](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) that works on both numpy arrays and Python native arrays. You can rewrite your code as:

```
def filterData(A):
    B = numpy.zeros(len(A));
    B[1:] = np.diff( A )/2.0
    B[0] = (A[0] + A[1])/2.0;
    return B
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also [`numpy.ediff1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html#numpy.ediff1d), which allows you to explicitly prepend or append to the diff using the `to_end` and `to_begin` parameters, e.g.:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10.)
>>> diff = np.ediff1d(a,to_begin = a[:2].sum()) / 2.
>>> diff
array([ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5])
>>> diff.size
10
```