# Python - checking if element is in list of lists (pythonic way)

Tags: python, arrays, list, search

suppose that I have a list "graph" initialised as follows.

```
graph = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 7]]
```

How would I then determine if 1 was in graph?

Is there a simpler, more optimized way than doing something like,

```
in_graph = False
for row in graph:
    if 1 in row:
        in_graph = True
        break
```

?

Thank you,

hob

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156087/python-search-in-lists-of-lists

Comment: Basically do the same thing as mentioned in the duplicate apart from using `1` instead of `''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
any(x in row for row in graph)
```

where `x` is the element you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any` with a generator expression.

```
any(1 in g for g in graph)
```