# Check if a word is in a list that is a value of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to check if a word is in a list that is a value of a dictionary.
For example i want to check if `'noodles'` is in:
`{1:['hello', 'hallo', 'salut', 'ciao', 'hola'], 2:['eggs', 'noodles', 'bacon']}`

I tried with:

```
element = 'noodles'
element in myDict.values()
```

But i get: `False`

Comment: `values` will return a list of lists in this case won't it? You'll probably need to check every sub list. `any` might be useful here.

Comment: You mention a list, but I don't see a list in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Your code checks if `element` (`'noodles'`) is a value in the dictionary, and it isn't (the values  are lists).

You need to check if `element` is inside every list.

If you don't care for the key:

```
print(any(element in value for value in myDict.values()))
```

If you want to know the key (this will print a list of matching keys):

```
print([key for key, value in myDict.items() if element in value])
```

**But**, generally speaking, if you find yourself having to loop over a dictionary over and over again, you either made a bad choice for what are the keys, or using the wrong data structure altogether.

Comment: i'd prefer `next((key for key, value in myDict.items() if element in value),"KEY_NOT_FOUND")`. But good answer (and yes, linear search in a dict is a clear indicator that there's a problem with the data organization)

Answer (score 1):

The `dict.values()` call here returns an iterable of lists. You'll need to flatten the returned iterable first, to test directly:

```
from itertools import chain

element = 'noodles'
print(element in chain.from_iterable(my_dict.values())) # -> True
```

Answer (score 1):

> You should use a function here , You can do with pure python without importing any module or making it more complicated :

Data:

```
Your_dict={1:['hello', 'hallo', 'salut', 'ciao', 'hola'], 2:['eggs', 'noodles', 'bacon']}
your_word='noodles'
```

code:

```
def find(dict_1,word):
    for words in dict_1.values():
        if word in words:
            return True
    else:
        return False




print(find(Your_dict,your_word))
```

output:

```
True
```

> One line solution without any for loop or module :

Just for fun

```
print(list(map(lambda x:x if your_word in x else None,Your_dict.values())))
```

output:

```
[None, ['eggs', 'noodles', 'bacon']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myDict = {1: ['hello', 'hallo', 'salut', 'ciao', 'hola'], 2: ['eggs', 'noodles', 'bacon']}
element = 'noodles'
[print(True) if element in value else None for value in myDict.values()]

# It will give true if it is present
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`any()`** on a `generator-expression`:

```
any("noodles" in v for v in d.values())
```

which, in this case, gives:

```
True
```

---

**why?**

Well `d.values()` returns an `iterables` of all the values in the dictionary `d`. So in this case, the result of `d.values()` would be:

```
dict_values([['hello', 'hallo', 'salut', 'ciao', 'hola'], ['eggs', 'noodles', 'bacon']])
```

We then went to check if the string `"noodles"` is in any of these values (`lists`) .

This is really easy / readable to do. We just want to create a `generator` that does exactly that - i.e. return a `boolean` for each value indicating whether or not `"noodles"` is in that `list`.

Then, as we now have a `generator`, we can use `any()` which will just return a `boolean` for the entire generator  indicating whether or not there wer any `Trues` when iterating through it.
 So what this means in our case is if `"noodles"` is in any of the `values`.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with loop.It will work definitely.This is tested code.

```
element = 'noodles'
for i in dict1.values():
    if(element in i):
        print(True)
        count+=1
print(count)
```

Count will count the number of occurrence of your element.If it is 0 then element is not
available in dictionary's values and if it is more than 0 then it is available in dictionary's values.Count is just for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.items()`:

```
s = {1:['hello', 'hallo', 'salut', 'ciao', 'hola'], 2:['eggs', 'noodles', 'bacon']}
element = 'noodles'
if any(element in b for a, b in s.items()):
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

myDict.values() will return a list of lists and not something you can ask x in y on, you won't be able to avoid a loop in some flavor similar to [Python search in lists of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156087/python-search-in-lists-of-lists)

...unless that is you find this time consuming and decide to keep some sort of hash to contain all elements inside the lists contained in myDict.values. Note though that this will take O(len(l)) for each insertion of l into the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to check if the word exists in either keys or values and here is a simple solution. (It may help someone)

```
if 'noodle' in str(myDict):
    True
else:
    False
```