# Return the key if the each word in a list of words exists in a dictionary having a list of words as value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a unique use case. The main requirement I have is efficiency and speed. I have a list of words of **40,000** in length and a dictionary of the format `data: {id1: ['hi','how'],id2:['I','love]..}` and of the length **250,000**. I have been going through many questions here on SO and could not find one which could be efficient.

How can I check if each word in the list of words exists in each dictionary's lists of words (values)? Normally, one could do the following:

```
all_words = get_vocabulary(data)
index = {}
for word in all_words:
    for doc, tokens in data.items():
        if word in tokens :
            ''' do something with key and tokens'''
```

By doing so, I can check if the word exists and do the rest. However, my dictionary and list are of huge size, and this takes a long time.

> If I have to go over a dictionary over and over again, it clearly marks a problem as mentioned by @DeepSpace [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619946/check-if-a-word-is-in-a-list-that-is-a-value-of-a-dictionary)

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to `do something` every time it's found? Or should it only have to do it once?

Comment: So basically, I would am creating a reverse index. If found, I will store the IDs where the word was found like so: {'love':[id1,id2, id3..],'hate':[id9,id1,id4].}

Comment: Oh, that is different than what I thought you were asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an index from your dictionary to speed up searching. For example:

```
all_words = ["word1", "word2"]

dct = {
    "id1": ["tis", "word1", "and", "word2"],
    "id2": ["word3", "word4"],
    "id3": ["word2", "only"],
}

# create index dictionary:
index_dct = {}
for k, v in dct.items():
    for word in v:
        index_dct.setdefault(word, []).append(k)

# index dictionary is:
# {
#     "tis": ["id1"],
#     "word1": ["id1"],
#     "and": ["id1"],
#     "word2": ["id1", "id3"],
#     "word3": ["id2"],
#     "word4": ["id2"],
#     "only": ["id3"],
# }


# now the search:
for word in all_words:
    if word in index_dct:
        for doc in index_dct[word]:
            print("Word: {} Doc: {} Tokens: {}".format(word, doc, dct[doc]))
```

Prints:

```
Word: word1 Doc: id1 Tokens: ['tis', 'word1', 'and', 'word2']
Word: word2 Doc: id1 Tokens: ['tis', 'word1', 'and', 'word2']
Word: word2 Doc: id3 Tokens: ['word2', 'only']
```

Comment: Even if this doesn't solve the OP's problem, really glad I read your solution. Been using python for quite awhile in my career and never knew about `setdefault` on a dictionary.

Comment: On the contrary, this exactly solves my problem and is super fast! Thank you!