# Search for combinations in tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
a = [[3, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)], [3, (5, 4, 3, 2, 1)]]

b = [[3, (18, 24, 21, 2, 3)], [3, (3, 4, 76, 7, 8)]]
```

How can I access `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, `(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)`, `(18, 24, 21, 2, 3)` and `(3, 4, 76, 7, 8)`?

I have to search for this elements in different lists.

For example: Is `(3, 4, 76, 7, 8)` in list `a` and if yes, what are the concrete numbers for this element?

( In that case [3, (3, 4, 76, 7, 8)] ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you mean to ask "how can I select sublists from a list where the sublist contains some specific element?" - i.e. `[x for x in a if (3, 4, 76, 7, 8) in x]`?

Comment: @Grismar Yes :-). I am not so long in this programing thing. Sorry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python search in lists of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156087/python-search-in-lists-of-lists)

Comment: @Grismar The answer from Samwise makes it. Its perfect for me. But thank you too for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [[3, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)], [3, (5, 4, 3, 2, 1)]]
>>> b = [[3, (18, 24, 21, 2, 3)], [3, (3, 4, 76, 7, 8)]]
>>> [x for x in a if (3, 4, 76, 7, 8) == x[1]]
[]
>>> [x for x in b if (3, 4, 76, 7, 8) == x[1]]
[[3, (3, 4, 76, 7, 8)]]
>>> [x for x in a + b if (3, 4, 76, 7, 8) == x[1]]
[[3, (3, 4, 76, 7, 8)]]
```