# How can i verify if a variable does not exist in a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension

I have the following tuple :

```
mytuple = (("azerty", "1"), ("qwerty", "2"))
```

I am trying to check if a variable is not in it:

```
n = 'azerty'

if n not in mytuple:
    print('not in the list')

> not in the list
```

I am trying to match the string "azerty" to each tuple in the tuple, So I tried to go 1 more layer into the tuple:

```
for mylist in mytuple:
    if n not in mylist:
        print('not in the list')

> not in the list
```

Now the problem here is `mytuple[1]` is matching my if, making me print.

Do you know how can I check if my variable is not in a tuple?

EDIT: This question was marked as duplicate. However, the [answered post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156087/search-in-lists-of-lists-by-given-index) refers to a slightly different problem. The original post checks existence by index and this problem wants to check existence for any element in the tuple.

Comment: You may find the builtin [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) helpful here

Comment: `if not any(i[0] == n for i in mytuple)`, `if n not in map(itemgetter(0), mytuple)`

Comment: `any("azerty" == a for a, b in mytuple)`.  Note that `mytuple` is not a tuple, it is a list...

Comment: As a quick comment, you actually are not working with tuples  in this problem. You declared a list. Tuples are enclosed in parenthesis `()`, and lists are enclosed in brackets `[]`.

Comment: @Arturo oops i made a mistake while typing. It is a tuple, i will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can do:

```
general_list = [("azerty", "1"), ("qwerty","2")]
n = "azerty"
in_tuple = False
for single_tuple in general_list:
    if n in single_tuple:
        in_tuple = True
if not in_tuple:
    print("not in the list")
```